# Group data.table dates into groups by consecutive time intervals (split by gaps)

Tags: r, data.table, time-series

I have a `data.table` with many events for different customers ("clients") and want to **split the events at each gap ("missing event") of the same customer**.

E. g. suppose I have monthly event data and a missing event for one or more months is a "gap" while events for several successive months belong to the same group:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)   # for ymd()
dt <- data.table(client.no = c(rep("Client_A", 3), rep("Client_B", 5), rep("Client_C", 2)),
                 event.date = ymd(20160101, 20160201, 20160301, 20151201, 20160101, 20160301, 20160501, 20160601, 20140701, 20150101))
```

With `dt`

```
    client.no event.date
 1:  Client_A 2016-01-01
 2:  Client_A 2016-02-01
 3:  Client_A 2016-03-01
 4:  Client_B 2015-12-01
 5:  Client_B 2016-01-01
 6:  Client_B 2016-03-01
 7:  Client_B 2016-05-01
 8:  Client_B 2016-06-01
 9:  Client_C 2014-07-01
10:  Client_C 2015-01-01
```

The result shall be a group number that is the same for each row of the same group, e. g.:

```
    client.no event.date group.no
 1:  Client_A 2016-01-01        1
 2:  Client_A 2016-02-01        1
 3:  Client_A 2016-03-01        1
 4:  Client_B 2015-12-01        1
 5:  Client_B 2016-01-01        1
 6:  Client_B 2016-03-01        2
 7:  Client_B 2016-05-01        3
 8:  Client_B 2016-06-01        3
 9:  Client_C 2014-07-01        1
10:  Client_C 2015-01-01        2
```

It is not required that the group number is reset to one for each client (but would be nice).

You can assume that the events are ordered within each client and that there are no duplicated event dates within the same client.

Comment: Maybe `dt[,group:=cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(event.date)>31)),by=client.no]`. Keep in mind that you cannot control in one line the units returned by `diff` applied to a `POSIXt` object, so it's likely that you have to check that the unit is `days` and then set the `>31` condition.

Comment: Excellent solution (what a pity that I cannot up-vote it more here without having an answer). THX!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `cumsum`:

```
dt[,z:=cumsum(c(1,diff(event.date)>31)),by=client.no]
```

Output:

```
   client.no event.date z
 1:  Client_A 2016-01-01 1
 2:  Client_A 2016-02-01 1
 3:  Client_A 2016-03-01 1
 4:  Client_B 2015-12-01 1
 5:  Client_B 2016-01-01 1
 6:  Client_B 2016-03-01 2
 7:  Client_B 2016-05-01 3
 8:  Client_B 2016-06-01 3
 9:  Client_C 2014-07-01 1
10:  Client_C 2015-01-01 2
```

Comment: Same line I suggested in the comments at the same time :) +1 of course (maybe add the warning about the units).